# Format empty matrix cells in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

When I apply a 0.00% format to a cell while designing an SSRS report, then export to Excel, only cells containing values have this number format. Cells without data default to the "General" format.

Is there a way to format empty cells so that they have the 0.00%?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if you set the value of a cell to "" (empty string) does the format carry through?

Answer (score 5):

You could try an expression like this in your cell:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!MyColumn.Value),0,Fields!MyColumn.Value)
```

If the field is empty then it puts 0, otherwise it uses the data.

Comment: 0 and null do not mean the same in this report, so I don't want to interpret null as 0.

Comment: I apologize if I'm misunderstanding, but isn't your question asking how to display an empty (null) value as $0.00? It looks like your main issue is exactly that you want to interpret null as 0.

Comment: No I do not want to interpret null as 0. I want blank cells to hold that format, so that if a user ends updating the sheet, he doesn't need to format again.

Comment: Ah, I see. And you're doing the formatting in the Text Box properties, not using the Format function in an expression?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the referencing of Empty Cell values using the ReportItem expression.

A solution is posted in the [article](http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?50106-conditional-format-column-containing-blank-cells) by darkdusky.

Use =ReportItems!textbox4.Value in the blank cells to make comparisons for cell values.